# Github renders bash script in the colab notebook with MathJax while it should not

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, mathjax

I have a cell in a Google Colab notebook, saved in a github repo. Some cells in that and some other notebooks are not rendered correctly in the github browse.

The actual code of the cell is:

```
!redis-cli $REDIS_CONN PING
!redis-cli $REDIS_CONN SET hello world
!redis-cli $REDIS_CONN GET hello
```

But then it is rendered in a [GitHub view](https://github.com/antonum/Redis-Workshops/blob/main/00-Setup/00-Setup_Redis_Workshops.ipynb) it's messed up (see picture below).

The problem is just with the github view - actual code after a local git clone or "open in colab" is still OK.

[image]

Original file is created in Github via Colab->Save a copy to Github, But persists after I change the code locally with VSCode and commit changes.

Anything I'm doing wrong here or any workarounds to make it render correctly?

**UPDATE:** After some digging, it appears that the string between two dollar signs is being interpreted as a math expression and is being rendered by GitHub preview with MathJax. You can actually right-click on the misrendered part and it will display MathJax menu. So the question becomes:

**How to selectively disable MathJax rendering within the GitHub notebook preview?**

Answer (score 0):

> How to selectively disable MathJax rendering within the GitHub notebook preview?

GitHub's Jupyter Notebook viewer seems to be treating the text between dollar signs as LaTeX expressions, which is a common syntax for rendering mathematical expressions using MathJax.

The closest I got was to percent encode `$` in `00-Setup_Redis_Workshops.ipynb`](https://github.com/VonC/Redis-Workshops/blob/patch-1/00-Setup/00-Setup_Redis_Workshops.ipynb?short_path=d49a1f8#L167-L170)

```
      "source": [
        "!redis-cli %24{REDIS_CONN} PING\n",
        "!redis-cli %24{REDIS_CONN} SET hello world\n",
        "!redis-cli %24{REDIS_CONN} GET hello"
      ]
```

It does not render the `$` in the regular GitHub view:

[image: GitHub view]

It does not either in the [collab view](https://colab.research.google.com/github/VonC/Redis-Workshops/blob/patch-1/00-Setup/00-Setup_Redis_Workshops.ipynb#scrollTo=6FFP3eCRBTzk)

[image: Collab view]

But at least, it is easier to read/interpret.

Comment: Metadata type is `code`. HEre is the link to the whole block: https://github.com/antonum/Redis-Workshops/blob/3d9084ac3f43348ea2a32c5c5265c32afe91e4cf/00-Setup/00-Setup_Redis_Workshops.ipynb#L146-L172

Adding the backticks to the code did not help. Cell now triggers an error, and github preview formatting is still invalid.

Splitting into separate cells one per line helps with rendering, but that's not something I'm ready to do here.

Comment: @Anton OK, I have edited the answer to add a few suggestions for you to try.

Comment: Neither of these options helps. Seems like the first time github sees a dollar sign - the rendering is messed up. !, %, %%bash, <!-- Bash Commands -->, single line - all with a similar (broken) result.

"Open in Colab" already does the same thing as you suggested with nbviewer, plus it actually executes the whole thing.

Putting the commands in an external file defeats the notebook's purpose - having all the code out there in the open, ready to run.

Comment: @Anton OK. Hopefully, your bounty will attract a better solution.

Comment: @Anton I have rewritten the answer and left some suggestions for you to test regarding LaTeX expressions to be disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help! Unfortunately, $$ doesn't prevent MathJax from kicking in and all the other suggestions prevent the code itself from executing properly.  Maybe next time you can try following "Open in Colab" button in this notebook https://github.com/antonum/Redis-Workshops/blob/main/00-Setup/00-Setup_Redis_Workshops.ipynb and testing the potential solutions? Just go to the `Runtime` menu and `Run All`

Comment: @Anton True, I did some testing (see my edited answer)